# Как вывести большое количество данных из бд в xamarin?

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin

У меня есть приложение, которое подключено к базе данных и выводит из нее данные, однако я вывожу данные (а если быть точнее, то поле Name) в элемент Label. И все бы ничего, ведь все работает, однако выводится только первый элемент в таблице, дальше ничего не выводится. Мне надо знать, каким образом я могу вывести все данные из поля Name (мне нужен сам алгоритм способа). На просторах интернета есть много ответов на эти вопросы, но мне нужно что-то более конкретное, быть может можно как-нибудь создать цикл, в котором при каждой новой записи создается новый Label, а может можно как-нибудь вывести в DataTemplate, если да, то как?

Comment: На мобильниках с базами данных не работают, потому что доступ к базе, открытый из интернета - дыра в безопасности, плюс логин-пароль доступа легче легкого из приложения достать. Мобильники работают с сервером, а сервер - с базой. Протокол клиент-сервер определяете вы.

Comment: Исходя из описания можно только одно ответить: у вас где-то в коде или разметке ошибка, и ее надо исправить. Больше по предоставленным сведениям сказать ничего не получится. Как я выше сказал, с нуля решение вам никто не напишет, потому что работа с базой напрямую с мобильника - ерунда и никто этим на практике не занимается.

Comment: Создаете коллекцию, читаете в нее из базы, отображаете с помощью, `ListView` https://youtu.be/71K4PVRLasI?list=PLwOF5UVsZWUiHY1CkRVjYJ6dm0iCvAlfw